# Show Discount value as Free Shipping

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

When I create a promo code for Free Shipping in Expresso Store (version 1.6.0), it appears I need to set the discount amount to 0 and choose option 'Yes' for Free Shipping.

This works - but when the user is shown the value of discounts on the order it shows £0.00 - which causes some confusion. I can't figure out a way to get the order_discount tag to show 'Free Shipping'. I've tried various conditionals but no luck.

Can anyone offer a suggestion on this?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to show if the applied promo code cause free shipping would be to use this in your template:

```
{if promo_code_free_shipping}
    Your Order Ships for Free
{/if}
```

Personally I don't consider Free Shipping to be a discount, like I would say $10 off of a $50 order so if I saw that the order now had free shipping I would see that the promo code had been applied.

However if you still want to do a conditional with the order discount try:

```
{if order_discount_val == 0}
    Free Shipping
{/if}
```

Any variable in Store that returns a formatted number `{price}`, `{price_inc_mod}`, `{sale_price}`, and so on can be postfixed with `_val` to have the unformatted number returned for use in conditionals and similar.

Comment: Ah great. Thanks. A combination of those 2 conditionals has done the job. I understand what you mean on Free Shipping not being a discount - but it made sense to be treated as one in this instance, just so users could see the order total had been updated after submitting their code.